# Blender 2.8 how to see rendertimes in RenderView

Tags: 3d-view

I want to compare my seen in 2.79 and 2.8 but in Cycles (2.8) I can't see the time how long it rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's still written at the top of the image viewer with render result opened:

[image: demo pic]

Comment: but not in the 3d render view thank you though

Comment: If you use EEVEE, yes it doesn't display the render stats in the viewport. But not Cycles.